# How to extract converge information in depmixs4 fit.mod in the form of 1 & 0?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

In package depmixs4, converge information of the HMM is shown in print(fit.mod).
However I'm trying to extract the value. For instance, when it converges I get 1. When it doesn't I get 0.

In this way when it doesn't converge I can automatically change to HMM with less states. 
But I didn't find a solution in the manual.

```
    for(i in 3000:(length(p[,2])-252*5)){
  mod <- depmix(p[(i):(252*5-1+i),2] ~ 1, data = p[(i):(252*5-1+i),], nstates = 3, family = gaussian())
  #set.seed(1)
  fit.mod <- fit(mod)}
```

print(fit.mod) will get

```
print(fit.mod)
Convergence info: 'maxit' iterations reached in EM without convergence. 
'log Lik.' 3478.027 (df=14)
AIC:  -6928.053 
BIC:  -6856.109
```

The problem is to extract the information "iterations reached in EM without convergence" as a number.

Comment: Please post the code you are running. For instance, one of the examples in the package's documentation, if it can illustrate the problem.

Comment: I've posted the code. The problem is to extract the information "iterations reached in EM without convergence" as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence return value is assigned in function `fit`. You can see exactly where in the code with

```
getMethods("fit", signature = "mix")
```

and look for the optimizers `Rdonlp2::dolnp2`, `rsolnp` and `solnp`.

A hack can be to extract the slot `message` from the object returned by `fit` and `grepl` an appropriate string.

```
converged <- function(object, numeric = TRUE){
  msg <- object@message
  if(numeric) as.integer(grepl("converged", msg)) else msg
}

converged(fm)
#[1] 1
```

As a test object `fm` I have used an example from `help('fit')`.

```
library(depmixS4)

data(speed) 
mod <- depmix(list(rt~1,corr~1),data=speed,nstates=2,
              family=list(gaussian(),multinomial("identity")),ntimes=c(168,134,137))
# print the model, formulae and parameter values
mod
set.seed(1)
# fit the model by calling fit
fm <- fit(mod, verbose = TRUE)
```